# IBM Cloud foundry java services app: Class Not found exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-cloud, bluemix-app-scan

I'm trying to run my java app on ibm bluemix. The app is deployed succesfully but it's unable to start. The logs contain an error message:

> Error: 2018-10-26T11:25:08.85+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error:
>   Could not find or load main class com.afpva.retrain.identify.RPConfigApplication

It's working as expected in the local environment. My manifest file is as follows:

```
applications:
- path: target/afpva-retraining-identify-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
  memory: 128M
  instances: 1
  name: afpva-retraining-identify-service
  host: afpva-retraining-identify-service
  domain: eu-gb.mybluemix.net
```

Comment: open your war file and check if the class exists there

Comment: Yes class is exists there .